# Query on the privileges of Builtin/Administrators group in Active directory

Tags: active-directory

If a *user account* is added to **builtin/Administrators group** in **Active directory** (not on any client pc or member-server) does it gives the privilege of both Domain Admin and Enterprise Admin to that *user account* ?

Since both Domain Admin and Enterprise Admin groups are members of the same builtin/Administrators group!

Answer (score 1):

> does it gives the privilege of both Domain Admin and Enterprise Admin to that user account?

No, an account does not get permissions from another account that is a group member.

Domain Admins actually gets most of its permissions from the builtin Administrators group.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yah,Domain Admins and Enterprise Admins actually gets most of its permissions from the builtin Administrators group.  My question was if we add a user account directly to the builtin/administrators group will he get privileges of both domain admin and enterprise admin?